# My harddrive is being weird

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, truecrypt

2 Months ago, i bought a WD Elements 2621 Hard Drive.
I encrypted it using Truecrypt 7.1a and it worked perfectly for 1 month, 3 Weeks and 5 days.
In the past 2 days, ive expierenced the drive getting hot, making clicky sounds, and terrible low transfer speed. (Before: 100MB/s) (Now: 1-3MB/s)
I think, my hard drive is dying. What can i do to save it? (I dont have enough storage space to store the data which is on it, and also it would take 2000GB * 1000MB/GB = 2000000MB
2,000,000MB / 2MB/s = 1,000,000s
1,000,000s / 3600s/h = 277 hours

How can i securely save my hard drive?

Comment: Truecrypt is unmaintained since 2014. The [sourceforge site](http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/) greets with a big fat red header saying " WARNING: Using TrueCrypt is not secure as it may contain unfixed security issues"

Comment: You cannot do anything to save your harddrive if you don't have access to a cleanroom and the same HDD as donor as well as specialized knowledge. Your best bet is to backup all your data and get a replacement drive under warranty. Using it any longer could result in catastrophic data loss.

Comment: Recovery by a recovery specialist is 500+ dollars.

Comment: Save the files for which you don't have other backups.

Comment: How much space is used on that 2TB drive? Are all files equally important?

The cause for your problems is not related to the use of Truecrypt. Any statements that you can't do anything to save the content of your harddrive are plain wrong.